# Cannot cast to java.Lang.Comparable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, exception, comparable

I have two `JFrames`:

`JFrameA` have a `JList` with a `cellrender` to display `Cita` objects, and a `JPopupMenu` that trigger a `JFrameB` to set and remove elements from the `JList`.

```
public class JFrameA extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public static DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    HashMap<Cita, Icon> elementos = new HashMap();
    Cita cita;

    //method to retrieve from DB the objects
    private void fillJList(){
        //create object to add to the model
        while(rs.next()){
            Cita = new Cita(rs.getTime("TimeColumn").....);
            model.addElement(cita);
            elementos.put(cita, aIcon);
        }
        jlistDia.setModel(model);
        RenderJList render = new RenderJList(elementos);
        JList.setCellRenderer(render);
    }
```

`JFrameB` receive a `Cita` object to update it and set it to the model of the `JFrameA`

```
public class JFrameB extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Cita objectToModify;

    public JFrameB(Cita objetToModify){
        this.objectToModify=objectToModify;
    }

    private void updates(){
        //get the new data of the object to set the JList of frameA
        Cita updatedObject = new Cita();
        JFrameA.model.set(objectToModify.getIndex(), updatedObject);
        //JFrameA.model is updated with no problems, but I want to sort the Cita objects by a Time param.
        sortModel(VistaDiaria.m);
    }

    private void sortModel(DefaultListModel model) {
        List<Cita> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
            list.add((Cita) model.get(i));
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        model.removeAllElements();
        for (Cita s : list) {
            model.addElement(s);
        }
    }
```

The method `sortModel` throw an `ClassCastException` and I don't know why, my `Cita` class implements Comparable this is the StackTrace i got.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: expeDiente.Cita cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:316)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:184)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1244)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:166)
```

`Cita` class:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.sql.Time;

    public class Cita implements Comparable<Cita> {

    public Time horaInicio;
    public Time horaTermino;
    public Paciente paciente;
    public String actividad;
    public String observacion;
    public String recordar;
    public String ciudad;
    public String TipoCita;
    public String fecha;
    public int idPaciente;
    public int idCita;

    public Cita() {
    }

    public Cita(String fecha, Time horaInicio, Time horaTermino, int idPaciente, String actividad,
            String observacion, String recordar, String ciudad, String tipoCita) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
        this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
        this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
        this.actividad = actividad;
        this.observacion = observacion;
        this.recordar = recordar;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.TipoCita = tipoCita;
    }

    public Cita(int idCita, String fecha, Time horaInicio, Time horaTermino, Paciente paciente, String actividad,
            String observacion, String recordar, String ciudad, String tipoCita) {
        this.idCita = idCita;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
        this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.actividad = actividad;
        this.observacion = observacion;
        this.recordar = recordar;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.TipoCita = tipoCita;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cita o) {
        return (getHoraInicio().compareTo(o.getHoraInicio()));
    }

    public int getIdCita() {
        return idCita;
    }

    public void setIdCita(int idCita) {
        this.idCita = idCita;
    }

    public Time getHoraInicio() {
        return horaInicio;
    }

    public void setHoraInicio(Time horaInicio) {
        this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
    }

    public Time getHoraTermino() {
        return horaTermino;
    }

    public void setHoraTermino(Time horaTermino) {
        this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    public String getActividad() {
        return actividad;
    }

    public void setActividad(String actividad) {
        this.actividad = actividad;
    }

    public String getObservacion() {
        return observacion;
    }

    public void setObservacion(String observacion) {
        this.observacion = observacion;
    }

    public String getRecordar() {
        return recordar;
    }

    public void setRecordar(String recordar) {
        this.recordar = recordar;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getTipoCita() {
        return TipoCita;
    }

    public void setTipoCita(String TipoCita) {
        this.TipoCita = TipoCita;
    }

    public int getIdPaciente() {
        return idPaciente;
    }

    public void setIdPaciente(int idPaciente) {
        this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 71 * hash + this.idCita;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Cita other = (Cita) obj;
        if (this.idCita != other.idCita) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatoInicio = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat formatoTermino = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        return paciente.getNombre() + ", "
                + formatoInicio.format(horaInicio) + "-"
                + formatoTermino.format(horaTermino);

    }

}
```

Comment: `List<Cita> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Have you tried changing this to

`List<Cita> list = new ArrayList<Cita>();`?

Comment: @SpacePope that's valid Java since Java 7.

Comment: Ah, right; that's what I get for working w/Java 6 all the time...

Comment: yes, and I still get the same exception, I made a simple project with only 1 frame, and no DB objects, and I used the same sort method and the same Cita class, and I got no errors

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón looks like you're importing this `Cita` class from another package and it's not the implementation you're seeing.

Comment: But if a debug it, and click into the declaration of the Cita object, I can see clearly the "public class implements Comparable<Cita>" line, and I discarded that option, rebuilding and replacing the .jar file

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón BTW you have a typo `starTime` at the fields declaration vs `startTime` at the constructor

Comment: That may be the current code for `Cita` class but not the definition used by the compiler.

Comment: How does the `import` statement for `Cita` look like in the class `JFrameB`? Also the `Comparable` in `Cita` is not your interface, right?

Comment: its not my interface, I'll try changing the package name of Cita, to see what happen. I comment after the test

Comment: god damn, I changed the package name of Cita and deleted the imports from the other project, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Cita` class as shown here doesn't compile.  So the compiled version that your other classes are seeing is not this one.  If you can fix the compile errors in your `Cita` class, the other classes will start working OK too.

Answer (score 0):

the definition used by the compiler wasnt the last implementation of my Cita class, I changed the name of the package and replaced the jar and the imports, and It works.